# Windows 8 slower games with nvidia drivers

Tags: windows-8, nvidia-geforce

I have a nvidia gtx 660m graphics card on my laptop. My problem is that games run a lot slower on windows 8 than on windows 7.

I have the latest drivers for my graphics card and I even tried some beta drivers but I get around 30% less frames per second on windows 8.

I read on other forums to wait for better drivers but it's almost a year since the gtx 660m was launched.

Answer (score 0):

Was this a fresh Windows 8 install, or an upgrade?

Try to fully uninstall the drivers, then reinstall the latest non-beta ones (this will clear any conflicting settings). Also, rerun the System Assessment tool after reinstalling the drivers.